# SQL - return distinct results from multiple columns regardless of order

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a SQL query (using PostgreSQL) that looks something like the following...

```
select 
    distinct
    t1.employee_name c1,
    t2.employee_name c2,
    t3.employee_name c3
from 
    table t1,
    table t2,
    table t3
```

To return all possible combinations from 'table' (yes, it's one single table). The problem I'm running in to, is that a result set of "A, B, C" and "A, C, B".

I need the results to be unique REGARDLESS of the order they appear in. So "B, C, A" should also be filtered, etc so the only rows returned have a unique combination of values without respect to their order.

Is there any way to do this in SQL? I may also add more columns in the future, so something that could support more would be ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can order your three fileds, adding this

```
where t1.employee_name < t2.employee_name and t2.employee_name < t3.employee_name
```

use <= if you want to allow repeated names.

Comment: This is a lot more simple than the other solutions I have been finding involving multiple subqueries. It seems like a great solution, let me just test it before I check it off.

Comment: it should filter out the rows where the three names are not in ascending order.